# Translation doubt: 自分とは何でどこへ向かうべきか

Tags: translation, particles

This is an excerpt from a song I'm trying to translate:

> 自分とは何でどこへ向かうべきか

自分 - oneself,

何でどこ - why, where,

向かう - head (verb),

べき - suffix meaning "should"

My doubts are what とは means and what is the role of か in the sentence? I can't give the whole sentence a general meaning. Can you help me, please?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,  「[何]{なん}で」 ***does not*** mean "why" here.  Thinking that it does would make one go crazy over this line.

> 「[自分]{じぶん}とは[何]{なん}でどこへ[向]{む}かうべきか」＝
>
> 「自分とは何で、どこへ向かうべきか」＝
>
> 「自分とは何であり、（そして）どこへ向かうべきか」　（あり＝あって）

「何」 means "what".  "Who" might fit better in the context, though.

「とは」 is an emphatic topic marker.  「か」 is a question marker.  Why am even I explaining these when they should be in the dictionary?

> "Who/What am I and where should I be headed?"

Comment: It could be read either なにで or なんで, but the singer seems to have chosen なにで: https://youtu.be/erGCAu_hFqM?t=1m59s